# How to implement dropdown in Plotly that will reupdate multiple graph instead of single graph

Tags: python, graph, plotly, dropdown

I am using dropdown to filter state in the line graph below. Here d is the dataframe, ther are 16 of them. In every dataframe I am trying to plot week as x axis and other values as y axis or traces in each graph. So far I am able to get dropdown menu for every 16 graph which would reupdate only given graph. Instead I want single dropdown value to update all the 16 graphs based on state selected on dropdown. Please see image attached.

[This is the image which shows dropdown for every graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78sGO.png)

This is my code:

```
state_list = list(df['GeogName'].unique())
for item in d.values(): #d is dictionary which has 16 dataframe as value, item is datafrme here.
    fig=go.Figure()
    state_plot_names = []
    buttons=[]
    default_state = "NY"

    for state_name in state_list:
        state_df = item[item["GeogName"]== region_name]
        for i in range(5): #adding 5 other traces as value in graph
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=state_df['Week'], y =state_df.iloc[:,i], line={}, visible=(state_name==default_state)))
        state_plot_names.extend([state_name])
    
    for state_name in state_list :
        buttons.append(dict(method='update',
                        label=state_name ,
                        args = [{'visible': [state_name ==s for s in state_plot_names]}]))


    fig.update_layout(autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=700,showlegend=True, updatemenus=[{"buttons": buttons, "direction": "down", "active": state_list.index(default_state), "showactive": True, "x": 0.5, "y": 1.15}])
    fig.show()
```

Comment: you need to start by considering the structure.   You cannot have dropdowns perform actions on independent figures (separate `go.Figure()` constructors). If you were to create as subplots it would be possible.  there are too many undefined parts of your sample code to be able to demonstrate, what is `d` a series of data frames?

Comment: @Rob Raymond Thank you for your response. I am sorry I have only provided code snippet here. In my case d is dictionary of dataframe. It hold dataframes which have the columns that I am plotting in my graph: Week as X-axis, State as filter(or drop down option), these 2 columns are present in all dataframe and other 5 columns, which are different in all dataframe are  "value" that are plotted as traces. This dictionary has 16 dataframe which I have plotted in plotly using for loop. Hence every graph has its own dropdown. I need help  with creating a single dropdown to get all 16 updated figure.

Comment: that's much clearer.  did you understand the point I made about many figures cannot work?  If you changed to subplots it can be made to work.  will subplots fit your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- have synthesised the **dict** of data frames you have described in comments, taking into account value column names are different in every data frame
- as noted, a drop down menu can only operate on a single figure.  Hence only option is to move to **subplots**
- the simplest way to achieve this is to structure all of the data frames into a single dataframe that can be used as an input to **Plotly Express**
- can now created a **facetted* (subplots) figure
- start by making default state (NY) only visible traces
- build drop down menu to control visibility for selection of other states
- did a bit of work on spacing between **subplots** as 16 leads to a lot of white space

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# replicate data described in question
states = ["NY", "NH", "IN", "CT", "MT", "VA", "ME", "SD", "KS", "MN"]
sigma = 0.01
d = {}
for di in range(16):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for s, (state, mu) in enumerate(
        zip(states, np.random.uniform(0.001, 0.005, len(states)))
    ):
        np.random.seed((s + 1) * di)
        start_price = np.random.uniform(1, 5, [5, 1])
        returns = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=100)
        df = pd.concat(
            [
                df,
                pd.DataFrame(
                    (start_price * (1 + returns).cumprod()).T,
                    columns=[f"value{di}_{n}" for n in range(5)],
                )
                .assign(GeogName=state)
                .reset_index()
                .rename(columns={"index": "Week"}),
            ]
        )
    d[chr(ord("A") + di)] = df

# integrate all dataframes so it's simple to use plotly express
# encode column name and GeogName into single column for definition of trace
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.set_index(["Week", "GeogName"])
        .stack()
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"level_2": "trace", 0: "value"})
        .assign(dataframe=k, trace=lambda d: d["GeogName"]+d["trace"])
        for k, df in d.items()
    ]
)

fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="Week",
    y="value",
    color="trace",
    facet_row="dataframe",
)

# default state...
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(visible=(t.name[0:2] == "NY")))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {"label": state, "method": "restyle", "args": [{"visible":[t.name[0:2]==state for t in fig.data]}]}
                for state in df["GeogName"].unique()
            ],
            "y":1.01,
            "x":.5
        }
    ],
    autosize=False,
    height=1500
)

# compress up space between subplots
fig.update_layout({
    f"yaxis{'' if axis==0 else axis+1}": {"domain": [s, e-.002]}
    for axis, (s, e) in enumerate(
        zip(np.linspace(0, 1, len(d.keys())+1), np.linspace(0, 1, len(d.keys())+1)[1:])
    )
})
```

[image]

Comment: I am able to synthesize all data in one dataframe. My final dataframe looks like:
State|Week|a|b|c|d|e|dataframe|f|g|h|i|j|dataframe|k|l|m|n|o|dataframe.............dataframe
NY|wk22|100|500|600|300|500|0|20|30|40|50|60|1|22|33|44|56|78|2.........................15, 
and my code is:
fig = px.line(
    df1,
    x="Week",
    y=[],
 facet_row="dataframe"),I am confused assigning Y value. how to get a,b,c,d,e cols for dataframe0 as one plot then f,g,h,i,j for df1, and so on upto dataframe 16 and have same name say A,B,C,D,E and distinct color for every plot for those five trace per state?

Comment: there are always 5 value columns?  if so I'd just make column names consistent before `concat()`.  in your question you implied they were the same...

Comment: By 5 value columns, do you mean 5 columns between every dataframe column? If so yes!! 0th and 1st are week and state, then it follows same pattern, column’s count wise: 5 columns. The columns and its value are different but we are giving it same name for every 5 column, say A,B,C,D,E for traces after being plotted in graph. More or less it is exaclty as example provided in comment above. Values are different, column name are different. Extremely sorry if my questions before were unclear. Also total rows are 10k.

Comment: so column name defines trace name?  That would mean a legend of 5*16 (80 items) if I follow correctly

Comment: Yes, You are right. 80 items are to be traced. But every subplots hold 5 traces.

Comment: ok updated data synthesis to match what you have stated,  column names are different in every data frame.  still same approach,  integrate data in data frames in **dict** into single dataframe and then generate facatted figure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71771108/plotly-is-showing-blank-graph-as-output-with-required-grid-x-y-facet-row-but 
The solution worked with the formatting but I am stuck right here, I was wondering if you could let me know what I did wrong, thanks in advance!!