# Plotly is showing blank graph as output with required grid (x, y, facet_row) but without data whereas it is showing fig (or graph) for other datasets

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, plotly

I am trying to plot the dataframe : [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBzCw.png) which has 5 columns, out of which, x axis should be week, geogname should be dropdown list, trace should be used as color and dataframe is facet_row, after plotting I should get graph something like: [expected graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYDDV.png) for every facet_row, but I have been getting something like: [Current_Output_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivDbb.png), what am I doing wrong?

Regarding dataset, there are almost 500000 rows, trace has same 5 values and is in order serially, and dataframe has total 16 type of values, for eg: 1 of them is CAT.

```
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="Week",
    y="value",
    color="trace",
    facet_row="dataframe",
)

# default state...
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(visible=(t.name[0:2] == "NY")))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {"label": state, "method": "restyle", "args": [{"visible":[t.name[0:2]==state for t in fig.data]}]}
                for state in df["GeogName"].unique()
            ],
            "y":1.01,
            "x":.5
        }
    ],
    autosize=False,
    #height=1500
    height=9000,
    width=1000
)

# compress up space between subplots
fig.update_layout({
    f"yaxis{'' if axis==0 else axis+1}": {"domain": [s, e-.002]}
    for axis, (s, e) in enumerate(
        zip(np.linspace(0, 1, len(d.keys())+1), np.linspace(0, 1, len(d.keys())+1)[1:])
    )
})
```

Comment: can you share your dataframe data as a CSV on a public cloud drive?  there's no point in me synthesising another data frame that works,  yet the specifics of your data are making it behave differently

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K4w23mveBbGX5L01-HPpEshzBUisYTXg/view?usp=sharing 
This is the file (data in csv format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- when you integrated the data frames, you did not concatenate *GeogName* will *column name*
- added one line of code to make it work

```
df["trace"] = df["GeogName"]+df["trace"]
```

- also modified the code to compress space between sub plots so it does not depend on the **dict**

#### full code with downloaded data

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(Path.home().joinpath("Downloads/data.csv"), index_col=0)

### trace has to contain GeogName so it is first two characters in trace name 
df["trace"] = df["GeogName"]+df["trace"]

fig = px.line(
    df,
    x="Week",
    y="value",
    color="trace",
    facet_row="dataframe",
)


# default state...
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(visible=(t.name[0:2] == "NY")))

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {"label": state, "method": "restyle", "args": [{"visible":[t.name[0:2]==state for t in fig.data]}]}
                for state in df["GeogName"].unique()
            ],
            "y":1.01,
            "x":.5
        }
    ],
    autosize=False,
    #height=1500
    height=9000,
    width=1000
)

# compress up space between subplots
fig.update_layout({
    f"yaxis{'' if axis==0 else axis+1}": {"domain": [s, e-.002]}
    for axis, (s, e) in enumerate(
        zip(np.linspace(0, 1, len(df["dataframe"].unique())+1), np.linspace(0, 1, len(df["dataframe"].unique())+1)[1:])
    )
})
```

Comment: This perfectly works as expected but while trying to run code without concatenating df['trace'] and df['Geogname']: with df['trace'] as df['trace'] itself only, it is not showing any data, so is there any logic behind concatenating these two columns (given we only need df[trace] as trace without concatenating geogname now as earlier one makes more sense to us)? Since all code is same compared to earlier, I am assuming either this line or not dropping index col in dataframe was creating an issue.

Comment: `{"visible":[t.name[0:2]==state for t in fig.data]}` its the absolute core logic,  first 2 chars of trace name must be *GeogName*

Comment: Got it, thank you so much, and sorry for all inconvenience as this is my first project with plotly and data.